# Why does FP-Growth return more than one Consequent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-mining, fpgrowth

I am using `fpgrowth` module from [Orange3-Associate](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html) to find the [*rules*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#Useful_Concepts) from transactions in a file. I am using this script:

```
from orangecontrib.associate.fpgrowth import *

transactions = [[1, 2, 5],
                [2, 4],
                [2, 3],
                [1, 2, 4],
                [1, 3],
                [2, 3],
                [1, 3],
                [1, 2, 3, 5],
                [1, 2, 3]]

itemsets = dict(frequent_itemsets(transactions, .2))
rules = [(list(P), list(Q), supp, conf) for P, Q, supp, conf in association_rules(itemsets, .5)]
```

However, when I `print(rules)`, Consequent `Q` shows as list of 2 or more items. Output:

> `[3, 5], [1, 2], 1, 1.0`

Why is this occurring? Isn't the Consequent supposed to be only 1 item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the consequent is not restricted to a single item.

If all your transactions contain A, B, then the rule `emptyset -> A, B` is the desired output to indicate that "no matter what the transaction contains A and B".

Comment: I ran Apriori on the same datasets, and I never got an output where the consequent consists of more than one item. Don't apriori and FP-growth have the same output?

Comment: Maybe the Apriori implementation is bad?

Comment: I'm using the [apyori](https://pypi.org/project/apyori/) package, which doesn't seem to have a bad implementation.

Comment: Actually that is so bad, it's not even Apriori. It's a naive interpretation of Apriori that missed all the clever ideas.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, I should have checked the source code. Do you know of any package which has a right implementation of it, so that I don't resort to reinventing the wheel (so that I can compare the results with fpgrowth)?

Comment: Pyfim looked very thorough to me.

Comment: just for clarification, the library that you suggest also restricts the consequent to a single item. http://www.borgelt.net/doc/apriori/apriori.html#conseq